# Changing foreground color of a TextBox control

Tags: c#, silverlight, expression-blend, controltemplate

Maybe this question is kind of silly but I have no clue how to solve the following (maybe trivial) problem:

I just want to change the foreground color of a TextBox control in Silverlight 4 so that in "Normal" state it is, say, black and in "Disabled" state it should be red.

So far i did the following: I am editing the controls ControlTemplate to manipulate the visual states of the TextBox  with the Visual State Manager in Blend 4 but because the text in the textBox is realized as its contentControl I can't find any foreground property to change the color or it to link to a particular visual state respectively.

Again, I simply want to set different foreground colors for different visual states of the TextBox.

Can anybody help me ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a couple things, You can delete the contentpresenter and replace it with a textblock, then with the TextBlock selected go to your Common Properties -> Text and click the little square next to it and choose Template Binding -> Content Which just adds a template binding for content to the control.

Or a quick an easy way is just wrap it in a usercontrol and apply your changes to it instead like

```
<UserControl>
<ContentPresenter....
</UserControl>
```

Then just choose the user control object and voila you can set foreground etc.

Comment: Hey Chris W. :) Thank you for your quick reply. Your answer was exactly what I was looking for. I simply deleted the ContentControl, replaced it with an ordinary TextBlock and the world is spinning again ;)

Comment: No worries glad it helped, all those render as textblocks at run time anyway, that trick comes in handy often. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

In the disabled state, you could set the Foreground property of the content control (if the template doesn't contain a content control, you could just wrap it around the content presenter):

```
<Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="Red" KeyTime="0" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```